# Is it possible to rebuild an app in eclipse/android studio using an apk file only?

Tags: android

- I made my app's interface online
- got it's ".apk" file
- Converted it into source code using the steps mentioned here
  [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)
- Now I have a folder containing all the java and xml files
- I tried importing it into android studio but due to gradle build issues which were beyond my understanding, I switched to eclipse to run the project but there are so many errors which I am unable to solve i.e errors in values that are too many.

I NEED this basic interface because I have to complete my project before the end of this month.

Should I stop relying on this apk file for my project or is there any way to continue development with this basic interface.
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add information about how you generated the interface and where you received the APK from? Also showing your errors would be helpful.

Comment: there is this free App builder website which allows you to develop apps online and then use barcode scanner to download them on your phone.
i tried it.used barcode scanner to download the whole thing. 
the app started downloading alongwith its apk file and when i found out that it really is a working app that's when i decided to decode the apk file.I tried running the code on eclipse but there are errors in "values" such as
Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format; did you mean to add the formatted="false" attribute? strings.xml /MainActivity/res/values-es Android AAPT Problem

Comment: what is your target? Create an Eclipse/AndroidStudio project from an APK?

Comment: Can you link to the App Builder site please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobincube doesn't supply a project download and unfortunately you are not permitted to modify the Mobincube generated app.

- Restrictions: Unless Mobincube authorizes, you cannot reproduce,
  redistribute or sell part of the source code of Mobincube’s web under
  no circumstance, neither mobile applications generated with it,
  changing, and compilation or reversing engineering. - See more at:
  http://www.mobincube.com/terms-and-conditions.html#sthash.l5hIu8kD.dpuf

Your options are either to continue developing using Mobincube and live in their system or to use Android Studio to write your own code.

Comment: Thanks for saving me from trying to answer the question. I fear Mobincube would sue me if I answer OP's question. :D

Answer (score 1):

I guess doing reverse engineering on one app built with [Mobincube](http://www.mobincube.com) can be fun. But you can go nuts if you want to make changes on your app. Mobincube apps are dynamically generated on runtime, so the same source code can have thousands of different behaviours depending on some specification files.

Imagine that you create a flash app. Will you try to do reverse engineering on the flash player in order to make changes in your app?

I guess you are trying to expand the functionality of your Mobincube app, since maybe their available functionalities are not enough for you. 2 weeks ago Mobincube launched a new feature and now you can expand your app's functionality by adding html/javascript modules and connect them with other parts of your app. It rocks!